# Is there an `if` syntax in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am looking for a solution to the following:

1. Go in to the `users` table and find a user who has listed items on the site.  In this `users` table, there is no column about auctions.  Instead, it is connected to an `accounts` table with a key (in `accounts`, this column is called `user`), so I used this to join them:

   ```
   SELECT users.id ,accounts.user FROM users
   LEFT JOIN accounts
   ON users.id = accounts.user
   WHERE accounts.user IS NOT NULL
   ```
2. From these IDs (users which have listed items for auction), I need to find their account balance.  This is also in the `accounts` table.  The balance is contained in a column called `operation_amount`.  I also have another column called `operation_type` which describes whether a user has a positive or negative balance.  For example, if `operation_type = 1`, he has a negative balance, while if `operation_type = 2`, he has a positive balance.

Now I have another table called `tmpinvoice` where there is a column called `amount`.  This shows how much in fees a user needs to pay to the site administrators.

Given this, I need to calculate how much he must pay in total.  For example, if a user has a $200 balance, I need to check whether it's negative or positive based on the `operation_type`.

Imagine a scenario where `balance - fees = total`, like `200 - 0.25 = ?`.  In this case, the amount calculated will be different based on whether the `200` is positive or negative.

I hope this is a better description.

Comment: The schema would be nice. Its a little hard to understand what you trying to say. Subtract 0.25 from what, or add it to what? The operation amount?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=sql+if

Comment: i edit it with full details

Comment: The language was difficult to understand, but I've edited the question and made it more clear to native English speakers.  I think overall it's actually a decent question which does show some effort, and the downvotes and close votes were mostly due to the clarity of the original formatting.  As such, if this gets closed, I'll also nominate for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to figure out what a user's total balance is. For example if, the user has a negative balance of 200 and owes .50 to the site operators, then it would be -200 -.50 for a total of -200.50 that she owes. If it is possitive then it is 200 - 0.50 for 199.50 that the company owes her. Did I get that right? The main part you are looking for is the CASE statement in the following queries. This solution is for SQL Server. Many other databases have similar CASE statement syntax, but this works on SQL Server as you can see on the SQL Fiddle link.

I am making things simple and assuming that there is only 1 account per user and 1 tmpinvoice per user. Since you specified in the WHERE clause "accounts.user IS NOT NULL" I changed the Left Join into an INNER JOIN which will accomplish the same thing.

```
SELECT 
 users.id,
 accounts.user_id,
 (CASE WHEN accounts.operation_type=1 THEN accounts.operation_amount * -1 ELSE accounts.operation_amount END) - tmpinvoice.amount AS total
FROM users
INNER JOIN accounts ON 
 users.id = accounts.user_id
LEFT JOIN tmpinvoice ON
 users.id = tmpinvoice.user_id
```

If more than 1 tmpinvoice per user you can do the following.

```
SELECT 
 users.id,
 accounts.user_id,
 MAX(CASE WHEN accounts.operation_type=1 THEN accounts.operation_amount * -1 ELSE accounts.operation_amount END) - SUM(COALESCE(tmpinvoice.amount,0.0)) AS total
FROM users
INNER JOIN accounts ON 
 users.id = accounts.user_id
LEFT JOIN tmpinvoice ON
 users.id = tmpinvoice.user_id
GROUP BY
 users.id,
 accounts.user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0b0d5/3) for working example

Comment: thank you can you check this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052032/how-to-sum-multiple-column-with-multiple-value

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX(CASE WHEN accounts.operation_type=1 THEN accounts.operation_amount * -1 ELSE' at line 4

Comment: Not sure what that error is, but here is a SQL Fiddle for MySQL 5.5.32. Same select, but DDL was different, so it works for MySQL 5.5.32 at least. Maybe you can edit your post to include the actual query you are using. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8965/1 Also, that other question looks to be that exact same question as this one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you want, but let me try:

```
SELECT  [user],
        account_balance + TotalAmount
FROM    accounts A
        JOIN
        (
            SELECT user, 
                    SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
            FROM   tmpinvoice 
        ) T
       ON   T.[user] = A.[user]
```

Comment: while that -0.25 is in diffirend table can i use SUM ?
in SELECT CASE ?

Comment: It depends on what you need. I would suggest providing "full" description and some sample data in your question. For instance say, i have two tables and add the columns that interest you for this question. Then add 3 or 4 rows of sample data for each table. A good thing would be adding a visual representation of your goal. As you can see there are plenty of us that would be very happy to help :)

Comment: Ok i edit my question whit full details

Comment: i need join also tmpinvoice(table) and do algoritham depends on  opperation_type to remove or plus operation_amount from tmpinvoice.amount

Comment: You really should provide schemas and requested output...

Comment: accoutns table = http://gyazo.com/3f39e46d8cbf8fb46e016b3827ce4b0c
tmpinvoice table = http://gyazo.com/31b86229fcdbe873b667f428eee3aeb7

Comment: Since amount has a sign, don't you think that always adding it it will either add or subtract? you may not need the case here.

Comment: what about 
CONCAT(
 CASE ac.operation_type
 WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('-', ac.operation_amount)
 WHEN 2 THEN ac.operation_amount
 ELSE 'N/A'
 END,

Comment: Why add the signs if they are already there?

Comment: Can you check my new query?

Comment: hm ok do you have idea how to  do it :(

Comment: still think should be CASE anywhere

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation for MSSQL IF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)

handling the Amount and Operation in variables for easier reading.

```
IF @OperationType = 1
BEGIN
 SET @Amount = @Amount  - 0.25
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SET @Amount = @Amount + 0.25
END
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do with `if else` in sql, here is syntax that I have used for mysql

```
SELECT IF(condition, true,false) from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for `case` expression

```
select case 
         when opperation_type = 1 then opperation_amount - 0.25 
         when opperation_type = 2 then opperation_amount + 0.25
       end
from tab
```

Comment: Please change 0 to 2 and the sign to be + in second case, just to reflect what is being asked.

Comment: @jyparask I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: Nit: `CASE` is an *expression*, not a statement. That's why it can be included inside of other expressions and actual statements.