# How to Sum multiple Column with multiple value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I am looking for a solution to the following:

1. Go in to the users table and find a user who has listed items on the site. In this users table, there is no column about auctions. Instead, it is connected to an accounts table with a key (in accounts, this column is called user)
2. From these IDs (users which have listed items for auction), I need to find their account balance. This is also in the accounts table. The balance is contained in a column called operation_amount. I also have another column called operation_type which describes whether a user has a positive or negative balance. For example, if operation_type = 1, he has a negative balance, while if operation_type = 2, he has a positive balance.

Now I have another table called `tmpinvoice` where there is a column called amount. This shows how much in fees a user needs to pay to the site administrators.

Given this, I need to calculate how much he must pay in total. For example, if a user has a $200 balance, I need to check whether it's negative or positive based on the `operation_type`.

So I have query where is Do this only for record

```
SELECT u.id AS id_user, u.nick,
  CASE ac.operation_type WHEN 1 THEN ac.operation_amount - tm.amount
                         WHEN 2 THEN ac.operation_amount + tm.amount
                                ELSE 'N/A' END AS `fee`                         
FROM auctionbg_search.accounts AS ac    
    LEFT JOIN auctionbg_search.users AS u ON TRUE
        AND u.id = ac.user
    LEFT JOIN auctionbg_search.auctions AS a ON TRUE
        AND a.id = ac.auction
    LEFT JOIN auctionbg_search.tmpinvoice AS tm  ON TRUE    
WHERE TRUE
  AND tm.amount = ac.operation_amount
```

Here what result I'm receiving

http://gyazo.com/3d7e7f52ee14d21cc8c8d33b6bbc479a

Yes but this calculate 'fee' only for 1 value in column , what if user have multiple values

like this user :

http://gyazo.com/c3bdb29fa235044ab888dc0385bbcdbd

I need calculate total amount from operation_amount  of that given user and remove `tmpinvoice` from that total amount  ,

A friend of mine told me to use

```
IF(SUM(ac.operation_amount), IS NULL , 0, sum(ac.operation_amount)
```

and to join 2 time accounts(table) for both case with + and -

join 1 time for + , 2 time for -

but I can't figure out how will looks :)

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: MySQL 5 why are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

Use CASE expression within the SUM function.

```
   SELECT u.id AS id_user, u.nick,
     SUM(CASE ac.operation_type WHEN 1 THEN ac.operation_amount - tm.amount У
                                WHEN 2 THEN ac.operation_amount + tm.amount
                                       ELSE 'N/A' END) AS `fee`
    FROM auctionbg_search.accounts AS ac
      LEFT JOIN auctionbg_search.users AS u ON TRUE AND u.id = ac.user 
      LEFT JOIN auctionbg_search.auctions AS a ON TRUE AND a.id = ac.auction
      LEFT JOIN auctionbg_search.tmpinvoice AS tm  ON TRUE  
    WHERE TRUE AND tm.amount = ac.operation_amount
    GROUP BY u.id, u.nick
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f66e/3)

Comment: This Would Calculate total column value in 1 , i need calculate for each user their balance not total amount in operation_amount

Comment: its give some unreal results here is result 
example user 37 http://gyazo.com/0bcf64d53d61dc2cb4a615d25ec3d4c8
show calculated fee 232 let see what have that user in operation_amount http://gyazo.com/96fbb0298f47671e38d7d6f9c40476a2
11.6 with + so lets check  tmpinvoice 
http://gyazo.com/0add00022a640ceb0dd864847d6584d9
no records in tmpinvoice so from where 232 is come then ?

Comment: Check entire request, including all joins but without the SUM function, maybe you have a 1:m associations

Comment: i dont get it what you mean

Comment: any otther suggestions?

Comment: Could you show an example of the tables(all tables) with wrong result (DDL+DML) on http://sqlfiddle.com, please

Comment: oh my god nobody cant help